# Is it legal to download paid books for free in Pakistan?

Tags: copyright, pakistan

Is it legal for me to download paid books for free from PdfDrive, as there are tons of paid books available there for free?

I live in Pakistan.

1. Is it legal to download it for purposes that are otherwise legal?
2. Why do the publishers who hold the copyright not take action against this?

Answer (score 2):

It is [copyright infringement in Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_Pakistan). [This article](https://pk.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/76/2016/03/ipr-copyrights.pdf) gives a brief overview. [This article](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0340035205061397?journalCode=iflb) studies piracy from a Pakistani perspective. Not everything on PDFDrive is guaranteed to be illegal, but a fair amount is infringing. One reason why such material persists is that copyright holders have to visit the site regularly and file DMCA takedown notices, but this is not limited to Pakistan. Typically, copyright holders are more focused on the distributors and not the end-consumers.